# Limit size of the REST request (GET)

Tags: actframework

I use Act.Framework for long requests, but I've noticed that the (JSON) response is truncated.

Is there any limit in the response size?

Ahmed

Comment: You should provide a code sample that demonstrates the error. Preferably, the smallest test set possible.

Answer (score 0):

ActFramework does not limit response size. If you keep getting the error, please fire a bug to https://github.com/actframework/actframework with the following information:

- version of actframework
- java version
- operations sytem
- hardware info, CPU, RAM
- is your app running in DEV mode or PROD mode

Better come up with a sample project that can reproduce the issue

Comment: I noticed this bug for ACT framwork version 1.8.29, java 8, windows. I updated my application to act.framwork 1.8.32 and it was OK.